# Outter edge table

Tags: math-mode

[image][image]

So, i've got this project to re-type a part of a math book. Could anybody please tell me how this would look like in a code. I mean the edge of the table not what's inside it.

that's my code around this thingy that should be right beneath 2nd line of this page.
Problem solved !
thx everybody

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the short compilable tex code you have so far! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! It seems more like a matrix (or determinant) than a table. See [this wikibook chapter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays) on typesetting math in LaTeX. Section 10 covers matrices.

Comment: @Mensch Ive got 500 lines of code so far. it's mid way in the document and its pretty much the last thing i'm missing as i've never seen such construction before.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It is possible to do using simple table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{l|l c r|l}
 
        & $a_{1,1}$ & $\dots, a_{1,n}$ & 0 &                 \\  
        & $a_{1,1}$ & $\dots, a_{1,n}$ & 0 &                 \\ 
        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\dotfill}   &                  \\  
        & $a_{1,1}$ & $\dots, a_{1,n}$ & 0 &                 \\ 
$d_{n+1}$ &         &                &   & = $\pm 2ad_n$ = 0 \\  
        & $a_{1,1}$ & $\dots, a_{1,n}$ & 0 &                 \\  
        & $a_{1,1}$ & $\dots, a_{1,n}$ & 0 &                 \\ 
        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\dotfill}   &                  \\ 
        & $a_{1,1}$ & $\dots, a_{1,n}$ & 0 &                 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\hdotsfor`.

In the first solution, standard centering is used. The second solution uses a personal environment so the alignment of each column can be specified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{xvmatrix}[1]{%
  \left|%
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
  \begin{array}{#1}%
}{%
  \end{array}%
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
  \right|%
}

\begin{document}

\[
d_{n+1} =
\begin{vmatrix}
  a_{1,1}   & a_{1,n}   & 0 \\
  a_{2,1}   & a_{2,n}   & 0 \\
  \hdotsfor{3} \\
  a_{j-1,1} & a_{j-1,n} & 0 \\
  a_{j,1}   & a_{j,n}   & a \\
  a_{j,1}   & a_{j,n}   & -a \\
  a_{j+1,1} & a_{j+1,n} & 0 \\
  \hdotsfor{3} \\
  a_{n,1}   & a_{n,n}   & 0
\end{vmatrix}
= \pm2 a d_n \neq 0 ,
\]

\[
d_{n+1} =
\begin{xvmatrix}{llr}
  a_{1,1}   & a_{1,n}   & 0 \\
  a_{2,1}   & a_{2,n}   & 0 \\
  \hdotsfor{3} \\
  a_{j-1,1} & a_{j-1,n} & 0 \\
  a_{j,1}   & a_{j,n}   & a \\
  a_{j,1}   & a_{j,n}   & -a \\
  a_{j+1,1} & a_{j+1,n} & 0 \\
  \hdotsfor{3} \\
  a_{n,1}   & a_{n,n}   & 0
\end{xvmatrix}
= \pm2 a d_n \neq 0 ,
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Very small variation of the @campa deleted answer (why you do that? your answer was very good, please undelete it, then I will delete mine). In comparison to it in my sugestion are reduced `\arraycolsep` to 2pt and reduced space around dots with comas (it is very strange to have comas after dots, this is mathematically incorrect, you should remove them).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
d_{n+1} =
\left|\begin{array}{l @{\; \dotsc,\ } lr}
  a_{1,1}   &  a_{1,n}   & 0 \\
  a_{2,1}   & a_{2,n}   & 0 \\
  \hdotsfor{3} \\
  a_{j-1,1} & a_{j-1,n} & 0 \\
  a_{j,1}   & a_{j,n}   & a \\
  a_{j,1}   & a_{j,n}   & -a \\
  a_{j+1,1} & a_{j+1,n} & 0 \\
  \hdotsfor{3} \\
  a_{n,1}   & a_{n,n}   & 0
\end{array}\right|
= \pm2 a d_n \neq 0 ,
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

and to my opinion more correct without commas in matrix:

[image]